# Thread safe queue (list) in .net

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, lucene.net

I need to create a thread safe list of items to be added to a lucene index.

Is the following thread safe?

```
public sealed class IndexQueue
{
    static readonly IndexQueue instance = new IndexQueue();
    private List<string> items = new List<string>();

    private IndexQueue() { }

    public static IndexQueue Instance {
        get { return instance; }
    }

    private object padlock = new object();

    public void AddItem(string item) {
        lock (padlock) {
            items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Is it necessary to lock even when getting items from the internal list?

The idea is that we will then have a separate task running to grab the items from indexqueue and add them to the lucene index.

Thanks
Ben

Comment: There are thread safe implementations in .NET 4 (if you can even use 4), not sure if you were aware or not, as I see you are rolling your own...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx

Comment: Thanks guys. Will have a look at System.Collections.Concurrent

Comment: I don't think `System.Collections.Concurrent` will be that useful to you. There is no `List` equivalent and even if there was you still might have to apply your own locking to cause the enumeration of the items to be atomic. It really depends on how you want the enumeration to be perceived by multiple threads.

Comment: Brian - the ConcurrentQueue was exactly what we needed. It's FIFO behaviour works for us. However, as you rightly said, we did need to introduce a lock around a call to Contains<T> to prevent duplicate items from being added to the queue - just to prevent a race condition from occurring.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your implementation seems thread-safe, although you *will* need to lock when reading from `items` as well - you can not safely read if there is a concurrent `Add` operation.   If you ever enumerate, you will need locking around that as well and that will need to live as long as the enumerator.

If you can use .net 4, I'd strongly suggest looking at the [System.Collections.Concurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) namespace.  It has some well tested and pretty performant collections that are thread-safe and in fact optimized around multiple-thread access.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it necessary to lock even when getting items from the internal list?

The List class is not thread-safe when you make modifications. It's necessary to lock if:

- You use a single instance of the class from multiple threads.
- The contents of the list can change while you are modifying *or* reading from the list.

Presumably the first is true otherwise you wouldn't be asking the question. The second is clearly true because the `Add` method modifies the list. So, yes, you need it.

When you add a method to your class that allows you to read back the items it is also necessary to lock, and importantly you must use the **same** lock object as you did in `AddItem`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes; while retrieval is not an intrinsically *unsafe* operation, if you're also writing to the list, then you run the risk of retrieving in the middle of a write.

This is especially true if this will operate like a traditional queue, where a retrieval will actually remove the retrieved value from the list.